# Rename [chantelise] → [chantelise-a-tale-of-two-sisters]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-rename-request

The game *[Chantelise – A Tale of Two Sisters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chantelise_%E2%80%93_A_Tale_of_Two_Sisters)* should be renamed to its full name, thanks to the 35 character limit.

- [chantelise](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/chantelise) → [chantelise-a-tale-of-two-sisters](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/chantelise-a-tale-of-two-sisters)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Done:**

- [chantelise](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/chantelise) → [chantelise-a-tale-of-two-sisters](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/chantelise-a-tale-of-two-sisters)